# If i can call the parent methods via this then why to use the super in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, super, ecma

Lets say we have a class **ABC**:

```
class ABC{
    constructor(param1, param2){
        this.prop1 = param1;
        this.prop2 = param2;
    }
    ABCMethod1(){
        console.log(this.prop1 + ' ' + this.prop2);
    }
}
```

And one another class **XYZ** that **extends** the class **ABC**:

```
class XYZ extends ABC{
    XYZMethod1(){
        this.ABCMethod1();
    }
}
```

So, ES6 introduced a new keyword **super** that is used to access the parent class members in the child class. But i can access the parent class members in the child class very easily by using the **this**:

```
var myObject = new XYZ('Property 1','Property 2');
myObject.XYZMethod1();
```

Which prints the following in the browser console:

```
Property 1 Property 2
```

Now lets do the same thing by using the **super** instead of **this** in the child class **XYZ**:

```
class XYZ extends ABC{
    XYZMethod1(){
        super.ABCMethod1();
    }
}
```

Now lets call the **XYZmethod1()** again to see what will be the result:

```
var myObject = new XYZ('Property 1','Property 2');
myObject.XYZMethod1();
```

Which prints the following in the browser console:

```
Property 1 Property 2
```

**Result:** Both **this** and **super** returns the same output `Property 1 Property 2` in the console. So, if we can access the parent methods using the **this** then what is the purpose of **super** in the ES6, why should we use it? Can anyone tell in easy words with example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the *same method* defined in the parent and the child class, `super` explicitly allows you to get the parent's implementation. Yes, Javascript (and virtually all other OOP languages) will traverse the prototype chain upwards to find properties defined on parents, so you don't *need* it to call a parent's method. In fact, you don't necessarily know how many layers up a method is defined, so it would be madness to *need* it. You only need it to disambiguate when there's more than one possible implementation (the current class or its parent).

This is mostly used when overriding the parent's implementation, but still wanting to call the parent's implementation:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {}
    bar() {}
}

class Baz {
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(42);
    }

    bar() {
        super.bar();
        console.log(42);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you used the **constructor() {super();console.log(42); }** in the child class what is the point of this in child class?

Comment: It executes the parent's constructor, and also does something in its own constructor. This particular example of course does nothing of interest, it just demonstrates this principle.

Comment: Even we can call **super.bar()** in **Baz** class without the **constructor() {super();console.log(42); }**, then why used the **constructor() {super();console.log(42); }** can you please elaborate?

Comment: Those are independent examples. It shows the constructor being overridden and the parent's constructor called, and it shows `bar` being overridden and the parent's `bar` called.

Answer (score 3):

It makes it more easy to call the constructor of the superclass:

```
 constructor() {
   super("param 1", "param 2");
 }
```

And it makes it easy to call a method of the superclass if it gets overriden by a sublcass (has the same name):

```
 class Animal {
  move() {
   console.log("moves");
  }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
 move() {
  super.move();
  // this.move() would end into endless recursion
  console.log("flies");
 }
}
```

Comment: its nore or more?